# How to get data from table-valued function?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm looking for another solution to get data from table-valued function.

I'm currently using

```
dbCommand.CommandText = "select * from My_function(param1, param2)";
dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

but I need the solution without using query e.g.

```
dbCommand.CommandText = "My_function";
dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
dbCommand.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
```

Unfortunately above returns an error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : The request for procedure 'My_function' failed because 'My_function' is a table valued function object.

Comment: Create a store procedure and inside store procedure call the function which return the data. After call that store procedure from the c# code.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't only one function. I don't want to increase elements in the database.

Comment: Maybe if you explain why you need this there could be another method to do what you need

Comment: I need a universal method to get such data without queries, new procedures and StringBuilders.

Comment: maybe you could figure out in your universal method if your dealing with a procedure, function, query or dml statement and execute the correct statements. So the caller does not have to worry about that.

Comment: I can't interfere with existing functions...

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm afraid of it.

Comment: I've edited my answer with an SQL Injection safe version.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't access a table valued function without selecting from it.

However, you can create a c# method that will generate the select statement for you:

```
public DataSet ExecuteTableValuedFunction(string functionName, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    var sqlWhiteList = "SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES " +
                        "WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION'  " +
                        "AND DATA_TYPE = 'TABLE'  " +
                        "AND SPECIFIC_NAME = @FunctionName";


    var sql = "SELECT * FROM " + functionName ;
    if (parameters.Length > 0)
    {
        sql += "(" + string.Join(",", parameters.Select(p => p.ParameterName)) + ")";
    }
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        using (var cmdWhiteList = new SqlCommand(sqlWhiteList, con))
        {
            cmdWhiteList.Parameters.Add("@FunctionName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = functionName;
            var exists = cmdWhiteList.ExecuteScalar();
            if (exists != null && exists != DBNull.Value)
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                    using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        var ds = new DataSet();
                        adapter.Fill(ds);
                        return ds;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note that this method use a white-list approach to protect against SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you, but for now I will be using query.

Comment: The method I'm suggesting is using a query :-)

Comment: Of course yes, but I thought about my query without a builder.